# How to view methods in textual order in Eclipse, for navigation in editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, navigation, package-explorer

I'd like to view a list of methods defined in a `.java` file in textual order, for navigating in the editor.

Currently I attempt to view the methods in `Package Explorer` with the drop-down arrow of the java class source file. It is sorted alphabetically which is not what I want. Tried to look around in `Ctrl`+`F10` in the Package Explorer options without luck so far.

How can I get a list of methods, sorted in their textual order (as defined in source code), for navigation?

Comment: You can `Ctrl-O` in the text editor to see all fields and methods in their order of appearance. But there doesn't seem to be any way to export that, not even by copypasting.

Comment: additionally, `ctrl+O` *can also* display the fields and methods as and how they appear in the java file. The order can be changed.

Comment: @TheLostMind You can click the arrow at the top right of the drop down to sort alphabetically.

Comment: @Mena TheLostMind Kon can this "*Open Declarations*" window be docked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use **Outline view**? Check [help here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcoutline.htm) and [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcoutline.htm).

You will get more options like: filters, hide/show fields, sorting etc.

Comment: oh, just forgot about that a long time ago. is that silly? :) thanks!